# How can I fix my selenium code with timeout exception error?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a selenium script in python that shows how many reviews a seller on bol.com has. Every time, I get the error `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`. Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
reviews = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='media_body'/following::p"))).text
print(reviews)
```

How would I fix my script?

Comment: Without seeing any of the HTML on the page, I'm willing to bet there is content being loaded asynchronously using JavaScript. You might need to scroll or interact with the page in another way before those elements get loaded.

Comment: I'm looking at that page and the element is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `requests` and `lxml`?  This may solve your problem...but like Greg mentioned, this depends on the website source.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

reviews = tree.xpath("//div[@class='media_body'/following::p")
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect expression: `//div[@class='media_body'/following::p`.

You can use this `xpath`: `//div[@class='media__body']//p`

```
reviews = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='media__body']//p"))).text
print(reviews)
```

Console output:

```
Totaal aantal beoordelingen: 6
```